# What is the ros::spin rate?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, publisher, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I need to run a moving robot in simulation and I need to know the translation and rotation of this robot. I was thinking to use the translation = linear.velocity *dt, and rotation = linear.velocity.z * dt. But I don't know what dt is. I have a subscriber with ros::spin() to subscriber the /cmd_vel topic.

1. How can I get the dt?
2. Does the dt strictly equal to the (1/publisher node's rate) ?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315473/what-is-the-ros::spin-rate?/) by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2019-02-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-13**:
I can also use the data in /odom. But I still want to know the dt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I need to know the translation and rotation of this robot. I was thinking to use the translation = linear.velocity *dt, and rotation = linear.velocity.z * dt. But I don't know what dt is. I have a subscriber with ros::spin() to subscriber the /cmd_vel topic.

The `cmd_vel` topic is typically used to *command* new velocity setpoints to a mobile base. It doesn't carry any state information in those cases -- only *desired* state. It would seem strange to me to use that to derive actual state of your robot, unless you don't care about discrepancies between commanded and actual state of course.

> I can also use the data in /odom.

The `odom` topic ([nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html)) does carry information about the actual state of your system. Both position and velocity, so the integration step has already been done for you (and possibly in a more advanced and robust way than simply integration velocity over a time interval, but that depends on the driver used and how that is written).

> But I still want to know the dt.

For message types that include a header (such as `Odom` and `TwistStamped`), I would advise you to make use of the `stamp` field in the header. If the publisher has correctly populated the fields, the `stamp` field should correspond to when the measurement (or calculation) that was used to populate the fields in the message associated with the timestamp took place (or was performed).

In that case, `dt` would simply be `msg1.header.stamp - msg0.header.stamp`. As long as you keep a single-message history in your receiving node, you can calculate the `dt` between two successive messages that way.

For messages that don't have headers (such as a regular `Twist`), you have two options:

1. use `ros::Time::now()` to approximate the time your code received the message as shown by @HankYuan in his answer
2. use a callback for a `ros::MessageEvent<M>` instead of the message type itself and use the *receipt time* as an approximation of when the message was received by the middleware

Refer to [wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers: Subscribing to a Topic - MessageEvent](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#MessageEvent_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D) for information on `MessageEvent`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-13**:
Thank you very much! This helps a lot!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
One thing to keep in mind: in message "processing pipelines" it's customary to keep the `header.stamp` of the source or origin message that was fed into the pipeline. All subsequent processing steps copy the timestamp of the incoming msgs into the outgoing msgs.

An example would be image ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
.. processing pipelines: the original image message gets a timestamp and every subsequent operation on that image results in a new msg which gets *the same timestamp*. Results of object recognition -- in a new msg -- also get *the same timestamp*.

This may complicate `dt(..)`calculation, but ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
.. but is often done to allow the use of packages like [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) to keep related (sensor) data temporally linked without having to create large messages that carry all results of the processing pipeline.

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-13**:
@gvdhoorn. Thank you. You mean there is some kind of time delay if the message has too much data? Do you think the message from 2d Lidar will be influenced?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
No, I meant to say that the `stamp` field does not always represent the time at which a msg was published *by the preceding publisher* (ie: the one that published that msg "last", in a manner of speaking).

It could be an older timestamp -- preserved -- such that temporal correlations can be saved.

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-13**:
Got it ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

1. You can add a member variable in your class to save the last time when you get to msg.

   ```
    class moving_robot{
    public:
        moving_robot() : last_time_(ros::Time::now())
        {
            sub = nh.subscribe("/cmd_vel", 10, &moving_robot::callback, this);
        }
    private:
        void callback(const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr &msg)
        {
            ros::Time curr_time = ros::Time::now();
            double dt = (curr_time - last_time_).toSec();
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("dt: " << dt);
            last_time_ = curr_time;
            // other works
        }
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        ros::Subscriber sub;
        ros::Time last_time_;  };
   ```
2. Yes, it depends on the topic frequency which you subscribe to and the callback function running time

Hope this will help!

---

Originally posted by [HankYuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37725/hankyuan/) with karma: 21 on 2019-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2019-02-13**:
Thank you for help!